# myComponent.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this information right now that i'm saving and trying to pass to a component who then tries to create Tabs and TabPanel (Material-ui components) with said info.

The declaration of that info goes as follow :

```
let eventCard = [
    {
        title: "Le sommet",
        learnMore: true,
        description:"5 jours de conversations inspirantes avec des explorateurs, des influenceurs et des experts qui réfléchissent au tourisme de demain.",
        eventCalendar: [
            {
                date: "3 mai 2021",
                location: "11h à 13h, Québec (UTC-4)"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "Le sommet",
        learnMore: true,
        description:"5 jours de conversations inspirantes avec des explorateurs, des influenceurs et des experts qui réfléchissent au tourisme de demain.",
        eventCalendar: [
            {
                date: "3 mai 2021",
                location: "11h à 13h, Québec (UTC-4)"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I then proceed to pass said info to my component:

```
<EventCard eventCard={eventCard}/>
```

On the other side i have an interface that contains the same information:

```
interface IEventCard {
    title?: string;
    learnMore?: boolean;
    description: string;
    eventCalendar?: IEventCalendar[];
}
```

and it is received as such in the function eventCard:

```
export default function EventCard(eventCard : IEventCard[]) {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

    const handleChange = (event: any, newValue: React.SetStateAction<number>) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
        <Grid className='EventCard-Background' container spacing={3}>
            <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                {eventCard && GenerateTabs(eventCard)}
            </Tabs>
            {GenerateTabPanels(eventCard, value.toString())}
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

In the console the object looks as follow:
[eventCard: eventCard Array(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBNPi.png)

The problem is that when i then try to use eventCard.map on it, it fails saying that eventCard.map is not a function and using Array.Array(eventCard) shows that eventCard is not even an array. I'm not sure to understand how to fix this problem.

Sorry if the question is a bit messy it's my first question here. I welcome advise in also making my questions more clear.

Comment: You have declared `eventCard` with `let`. Does some other part of your code change it to something else? As for feedback, for clarity of both your question and code use plurals where it makes sense, i.e. you should have named your array eventCard*s*.

Comment: a function component takes props as an object, which has all the attributes, not directly. Also, are you missing a `reactjs` tag?

Comment: I imported React from 'react' if that's what you mean. And thank you Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must receive props and use props.EventCard inside component or either desctruct it with {eventCard}

```
export default function EventCard(props)
```

or

```
export default function EventCard({eventCard : IEventCard[]})
```

gl

Comment: Thank you! Doing export default function EventCard(props : any) seems to fix my current issue